# I cannot see the child java process from ruby process

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I run from the first irb console:

```
fork { system 'webdriver-manager start --standalone' }
```

run from the second irb console:

```
`ps aux | grep -ie '\-Dwebdriver' | grep -v grep`
```

So I receive nothing. Though I see the process from terminal:

```
$ ps aux | grep -ie '\-Dwebdriver' | grep -v grep

...    24762  2.5  0.6 4752104 49180 pts/2   Sl+  15:44   0:00 java -jar /home/.../.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/home/.../.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver
```

Why I cannot see the java process from ruby process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps aux` will truncate the output to the width of your terminal. I bet if you were to expand your terminal where you run your second irb session, it would show. Use `ww` so it doesn't truncate.

```
`ps auxww | grep -ie '\-Dwebdriver' | grep -v grep`
```

Comment: No, the command in the second terminal returned the empty string. Thanks.

Comment: Did you even try to run it?